# How to write java class methods that can accept groovy closures

Tags: java, groovy

Here's what I want to do:

I have a class called `RowCollection` which contains a collection of `Row` objects, with a method named `edit`, which is supposed to accept as a parameter another method (or closure) which operates on a `Row` object.

A groovy script will be using an object of this class in the following way:

```
rc.edit({ it.setTitle('hello world') }); // it is a "Row" object
```

My questions:

1. what will the signature of `RowCollection#edit` look like?
2. what can its implementation look like?

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, if you make `RowCollection` implement `Iterable<Row>` and provide a suitable `iterator()` method then the standard Groovy-JDK magic applied to all classes will enable

```
rc.each { it.title = "hello world" }
```

and you get all the other `iterator`-backed GDK methods for free in the same way, including `collect`, `findAll`, `inject`, `any`, `every` and `grep`.

Answer (score 2):

Okay - a little bit of digging, and here it is:

```
class RowCollection {
    private List<Row> rows;

    // ...

    public void edit(Closure c) {
        for(Row r : rows) {
            c.call(r);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

the class Closure is in `groovy.lang` package.

Comment: `c.call` not `c.calls`, surely?

Comment: also, `foreach( Row r : rows )` you probably meant `for( Row r : rows )`

Comment: that's right - made edits. Feel free to make edits on typos :)